# Runtime Code Coverage Tools

Tags: c#, .net, profiling, code-coverage

I know that there are a number of tools for analysing .NET code and calculating the coverage, plus identifying classes/methods/properties etc that are never going to be hit.

However, I am trying to clean-up a legacy application that I am certain contains an amount of unused code - however a lot of code is accessed via some arbitrary and complex reflection tecniques that will disguise the intent to the compiler - thererfore any coverage tool that only analyses the compiled code is unlikely to generate any reliable reports on code useage within this application.

Are there any tools that work rather like profilers, whereby they listen to a running application and log what classes/methods/properties are actually hit and generate the coverage based on this data.

I hope Ive made everything clear - thanks in anticipation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the VS2010 Code Coverage tools - they do use Instrumentation (which means reflection won't trick it). Syed Aslam Basha has a [post on it](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/syedab/archive/2011/03/11/c-code-coverage-using-vs2010.aspx) in his MSDN blog on how to enable it for manual testing (which it sounds like you will need to do).

Just remember you will need to click every feature etc. while its running; or just think twice before deleting code - but it should give you a good starting point.

Answer (score 2):

we are using ncover, and it works really nicely: http://www.ncover.com/.
But it's commerical, or you use the trial version, if you just need it once.

Answer (score 1):

Two open source versions currently exist that support .NET2 and .NET4 runtimes

[PartCover](https://github.com/sawilde/partcover.net4) - is the oldest but only supports 32 bit (supported by teamcity)

and

[OpenCover](https://github.com/sawilde/opencover) - is the latest, it again supports .NET2 and .NET4 but also supports 64 bit, it also has recently added branch coverage (though reporting is up to the user)

Both OpenCover and PartCover can be used with TypeMock and Moles should you need to.

Commercial versions include (but no limited to)

[NCover](http://www.ncover.com/) - the most well known

[dotcover](http://www.jetbrains.com/dotcover/) - integrates well with team city when unit testing

Answer (score 0):

Clover.NET can do this. But it is commercial and I didn't manage to find a link to the .NET version (I've used it several year ago).

Answer (score 0):

Can't think of a tool other than a profiler, but how about using logging?

Use static analysis to discover static calls, and put logging into the reflective invocations to show what is being called. After a few runs you'll know what is being run.

After all the reflective invocation will know what's doing.